# Setup a full node to use history plugin | docker quickstart sufficient?

Tags: docker, node, history

Is the [docker quickstart](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart) sufficient to run a full node so I can query all incoming & outgoing transactions using the history plug in?
Or should I go for the full installation?

Currently trying to set up a full node using digitalocean and [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@master_32654/how-to-build-bp-like-a-boss-build-bp-docker-image-aa890b7f574d)

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient. As long as you have server powerful enough. Especially storage.

Comment: so how can I disable plugins or use the history plugin? With the compiled version, I use config.ini , can't find it in Docker atm